# How to get the successive months in java script?

Tags: javascript, date

I need to get the successive months from the date the user has entered. And also the user will   enter the number of successive months he/she wants to be displayed.

eg: Date  Month  Year
    08    05     2012 - This date is given as input.

```
Enter the number of months - 4 - This also given as input by the user.
```

Now I need to display the next 4 month?

Comment: It's not that hard. You just can keep a list with all months and use the given month as an offset into the list.

Comment: I am a beginner, so I have completed only the design. I have used a button in my page to execute. After the user enters the date and the number of months to be displayed we have to display the successive years of the same date.

Comment: Hi Sven I cant understand. Please make it brief.

Answer (score 0):

Simple basic JavaScript Code for this is

```
<input type="text" id="mnt"/>
<a href="javaScript:getNextMonths()">Get Next</a>
<div id="nxt" ></div>​
```

Above is your HTML code where result will be shown in the div inner html

```
var monthArray = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
var msg = 'Please provide proper value';
getNextMonths = function(){
    var curMonth = document.getElementById('mnt').value/1;
    var nxtM = curMonth ;
    var cntMnt = 1;
    try{
        msg = '';
        do{
            if(nxtM >= 12)
               nxtM = 0; 
               msg = msg + ' ' +monthArray[nxtM];
               cntMnt = cntMnt + 1;   
          nxtM++;           
        }while(cntMnt < 5);

    }catch(e){alert(e);}
    document.getElementById('nxt').innerHTML=msg;
}​
```

And the JavaScript code is as above. This will also need to validated more.

Please refer this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/R9gWt/1/)

Comment: @RamMessi, Do you think there is anything remaining or missing in this, I suggest use jsfiddle for updating the answer.